# Trying to display Hello World character on android phone using native code

Tags: android, arm

using stdout library it will maybe pass data to logcat or somewhere else which is not heading toward to display screen.

How can I manage to display what I want using native code with out passing dalvik...T_T

Comment: If you want to write pure native code that uses no Android components, you are able to write native Linux applications. The phone must be rooted and your interaction with your app will take place in an ADB shell. STDOUT will be displayed in the shell window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may well be no officially supported way to do that.  Android is fairly fundamentally based around java code running in the dalvik virtual machine.

It used to be your only option was to use jni between your own native and java code to pass the data through to the java-level Android display APIs.

In more recent versions, it is possible to write a so-called native activity where all of your code is C or C++.  However, such an activity still runs in a process built around a dalvik virtual machine running platform-supplied java code, and calling into your code via jni.

There is an embedded Open GL native API which you could use to plot text, but it is quite likely that behind the scenes some jni is still involved, at the very least in the setup of the views.

Both the native activity and native use of open GL have examples in the ndk distribution.

I suppose you could also have you code interact via pipes or sockets with a different process which would display its output, but that's just moving the use of dalvik elsewhere.

Comment: I was thinking...what if I change boot loader arguments and connect display driver to android console.... ???

Comment: Yes, you could do that.  Not so much at bootloader level perhaps but just changing the init scripts to start your privileged native process instead of the dalvik-based android runtime - you could probably learn from some of the custom recovery images which seem to have a UI perhaps without an android runtime.

Comment: Or even the stock recovery - look in platform/bootable/recovery.git - see ui.c and the miniui/ directory.